# Unity Container Dependency Injection - How Would I Register This?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an interface, ICrudService, and a service that implements the interface, CrudService. I am trying to use Unity for dependency injection purposes, but I can't see to figure out how to register the type.

Here is my ICrudService:

```
public interface ICrudService<T> where T: DelEntity, new()
{
    int Create(T item);
    void Save();

    T Get(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> func, bool showDeleted = false);
}
```

Here is my CrudService:

```
public class CrudService<T> : ICrudService<T> where T : DelEntity, new ()
{
    protected IRepo<T> repo;

    public CrudService(IRepo<T> repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return repo.GetAll();
    }

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return repo.Get(id);
    }

    public virtual int Create(T item)
    {
        var newItem = repo.Insert(item);
        repo.Save();
        return newItem.Id;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        repo.Save();
    }

    public virtual void Delete(int id)
    {
        repo.Delete(repo.Get(id));
        repo.Save();
    }

    public void Restore(int id)
    {
        repo.Restore(repo.Get(id));
        repo.Save();
    }

    public void BatchDelete(int[] ids)
    {
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            repo.Get(id).IsDeleted = true;
        }

        repo.Save();
    }

    public void BatchRestore(int[] ids)
    {
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            repo.Get(id).IsDeleted = false;
        }

        repo.Save();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, bool showDeleted = false)
    {
        return repo.Where(predicate, showDeleted);
    }
}
```

And finally, my UnitConfig.cs, which I can't even get to build...

```
public class UnityConfig
{
    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the configured Unity container.
    /// </summary>
    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return container.Value;
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.</summary>
    /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
    /// <remarks>There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or API controllers (unless you want to 
    /// change the defaults), as Unity allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously registered.</remarks>
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
        // container.LoadConfiguration();

        // TODO: Register your types here
        container.RegisterType<ICrudService<T>, CrudService<T>>();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in the UnityConfig.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting is a C# compiler error stating that `T` is unknown. This is the way to register generic types in Unity:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(ICrudService<>), typeof(CrudService<>));
```